# Golang source files are gone in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My Google Cloud App Engine is just missing some of the more recent source code files (like Golang packages I wrote) today.

URLs like `myproject.appengine.com/mynewfeature` don't work anymore.

It seem Google just deleted my latest work and reverted to an old version, maybe 5 days old.

If I write `history` in Terminal it does not show the most recent history.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: I'm quite lost. You talked about your App Engine service that is down, and then  you talked about your terminal (Cloud Shell?) without history. What do you want to fix? Can be more precise?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sorry for the confusion, the site is not down, just some URLs that rely on code that is gone. Yes the Cloud Shell, command line history and directory structure are acting like the work I did in the last week never occurred. I guess it's a different virtual machine somehow?

Comment: Ok, you are working on Cloud Shell and your work of the last week has disappeared. So, your App Engine behavior is strange. You can check what happened in the audit logs. About Cloud Shell, maybe that your most recent disk image was corrupted and Google load a previous backup. No link with the VM, the compute (the VM) is not linked to your data (disk image).

Answer (score 1):

Google provides Debbuger functionality, that might be helpful in your case. I never heard of loosing any code in App Engine, so I suppose it must be something else.

When you open your App Engine Services on GCP ([direct link](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/services)) each service has "Tools" at the end of each line. There you can choose "source". When you choose this you will be taken to Debugger ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs)). Than just behind "Debbuger" inscription you can choose version of your source. You can review your all deploys there, historical as well.

I hope it will help you to find the problem root cause.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find most of the lost source code under Debugger -> Deployed files. Not quite all though... it only has the code that was part of a Version and where that version was not since overwritten or deleted